# Search firebase database for Sport instead of Gender

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an application similar to tinder but to help users to find people to play a specific sport with. 
I currently have the code searching the database for the gender of the users (that the user can be matched with). However each user in the database has a node that contains all of the sports the user can pick. If the user prefers a sport the value is saved as 'true' and if not, the value is saved as 'false'. The appropriate users are then shown on the app.

A screenshot of the database is shown below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdefD.png]

This is the code I have so far:

```
 public void checkUserSex(){
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference userDb = usersDb.child(user.getUid());
    userDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                if (dataSnapshot.child("sex"). getValue() != null){
                    userSex = dataSnapshot.child("sex").getValue().toString();
                    switch (userSex){
                        case "Male":
                            oppositeUserSex = "Female";
                            break;
                        case "Female":
                            oppositeUserSex = "Male";
                            break;
                    }
                    getOppositeSexUsers();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

public void getOppositeSexUsers(){
    usersDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("sex").getValue() != null) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("pass").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("play").hasChild(currentUId) && dataSnapshot.child("sex").getValue().toString().equals(oppositeUserSex)) {
                    String profileImageUrl = "default";
                    if (!dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().equals("default")) {
                        profileImageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().toString();
                    }
                    cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(), profileImageUrl);
                    rowItems.add(item);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

How do I change it from matching gender to matching the selected sport?

Comment: The problem with your current data structure is that you'd need to define an index on each individual `Sport` value, which is often not feasible. That's why it's better to create your own inverted lookup structure, as Alex' answer shows. For another explanation, have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firebase Realtime database does not allow a query based on multiple properties. To achieve what you want, you don't need to restructure your database entirely, you just need to change it a little bit. To solve this problem, you need to add a new node for each sport. Every time you add a new user which plays `golf`, add it also in its corresponding sport node. Your new node should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- golfPlayers
           |
           --- userId1 : true
           |
           --- userId2 : true
```

With this structure you can query your database to get only the users who are playing `golf`. This can be done by attaching a listener on `golf` node and iterate on the `DataSnapshot` object.

This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

Note, what you are trying to do and cannot be solved using Firebase Realtime database, can be solved using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). Give it a try.

Comment: This is part of denormalization as it is duplicating data, is specifically called indexing. Btw your Firestore suggestion is wonderful.

Comment: @cutiko Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, I managed to edit it all so the database appears as suggested. Any tips on using firestore to match the rest?